# How to phone call from listview having name and number in arraylist

Tags: android

I am unable to call when clicking on the list view having name and mobile number.

Further, when click event happen then how to get mobile number from arraylist everytime click on listview.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.vinod.mycommunity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void contactClick (View view){

        // Create a new intent to open the {@link NumbersActivity}
        Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactList.class);

        // Start the new activity
        startActivity(numbersIntent);
    }
}
```

Custom Object

```
    package com.example.vinod.mycommunity;



/**
 * Created by vinod on 24/8/17.
 */

public class CustomContactList {

    private String mNames;
    private String mNumber;


    public CustomContactList(String Names, String Numbers) {
        mNames = Names;
        mNumber = Numbers;
    }

    public String getmNames() {
        return mNames;

    }

    public String getmNumber() {
        return mNumber;

    }

}
```

Contact List Activity

```
package com.example.vinod.mycommunity;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ContactList extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

        // Create an arrayList of Contact Name and contact Number
        ArrayList<CustomContactList> contactsArray = new ArrayList<CustomContactList>();

        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Vinod Lohar", "9987376064"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Mukesh Lohar", "9983154742"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Arjun Lohar", "9694544296"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Sapna Lohar", "9521130633"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Ramesh Lohar", "7718835888"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Manju Lohar", "9029788725"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Jagdish Lohar", "9987409707"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Rekha Lohar", "9001239708"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Jyoti Lohar", "9828146608"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Dinesh Lohar", "9521663206"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Chunnibai Lohar", "9521085134"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Rekha Lohar Udaipur", "9828504595"));
        contactsArray.add(new CustomContactList("Jagdish Ji Lohar Udaipur", "9828119641"));


        ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, contactsArray);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Custom Adapter

```
package com.example.vinod.mycommunity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by vinod on 25/8/17.
 */

public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomContactList> {

    public ContactAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<CustomContactList> contactsArray) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, contactsArray);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the CustomContactList object located at this position in the list
        CustomContactList currentContactList = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID Name_TextView
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Name_TextView);
        // Get the contact name from the current CustomContactList object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        nameTextView.setText(currentContactList.getmNames());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the Id Number_TextView
        TextView numberTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Number_TextView);
        // Get the contact number from the current CustomContactList object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        numberTextView.setText(currentContactList.getmNumber());

        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Main Activity Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#a4c639"
        android:onClick="contactClick"
        android:text="Contacts"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

List Item Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Names" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Number_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Numbers" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Contact List Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="com.example.vinod.mycommunity.ContactList">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Contacts"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is that *really* a *minimal* example?  Read [mcve] and consider what you might [edit] to reduce the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Implement an ItemClickListener for the listView inside Contact List Activity

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int     position, long l)
{    
    // Get Phone Number    
    String phone = ((CustomContactList)adapter.getItem(position)).getmNumber();

    // Make a call
    Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
    startActivity(phoneIntent);
}
```

Set List Item Click Listener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```